# Drupal: Exporting current content into editable format

Tags: drupal, export

We need to export all of the content from a current Drupal website into an editable format (XML, XLS, etc.)  so that the content can then be translated into a different language.

Is there a clean way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Node Export module](https://drupal.org/project/node_export). It appears you can also do it with [Drush](https://drupal.org/project/drush).

This post https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/63055/how-to-export-nodes-as-xml has some detailed info on exporting nodes to XML from both command line and using the GUI. Both answers are worth reading depending on which approach you choose to take.